# Call a function with two parameters from #selector in cellForItemsInSection

Tags: swift, function, uicollectionviewcell

This is my function:

```
func myFunction(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer, index: Int){
print(sender.view?.tag)
}
```

In cellForItemsInSection this is what I do:

```
let gesture  UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myFunction(_:))) //here I want to call the second parameter with the indexPath.row but how? 
gesture.view?.tag = indexPath.row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass two parameters in an UIGestureRecognizer action as @vadian said.

you can simply do this to get indexPath.row in your function

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
gesture.view?.tag = indexPath.row
gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myFunction(_:)))
```

and in your `myFunction`

```
func myFunction(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
  let tag = sender.view?.tag


  //do stuff

  }
```

Comment: I did this but in my function, calling print(sender.view.tag) it's always 0, the default value

Comment: probably you are setting tag before adding gesture  on view . set it after adding gesture on view.

Comment: let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
// add gesture on view 
then gesture.view?.tag = indexPath.row

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass two parameters in an `UIGestureRecognizer` action.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer):

> The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following
>   signatures:
>
> `- (void)handleGesture;`
>   `- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;`

Comment: Great. I didn't know that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer() 
gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myFunction(sender:index:)))
```

If you prefix your `selector` with the class you can get code completion.

So if you have `MyViewController` with `myFunction`, you can write

`gesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.))`

and code completion should help you from there as you can see in this image (and yes, I was in a class called `CreateUserViewController` but just ignore that :))

[image: code completion in action]

Hope that helps you.

### Edit

@vadian is right. I'll leave this answer though so you can see how to use code completion but my answer is not correct, vadians is.